# ".NET Core Host" hogging CPU

Tags: windows-10, cpu, .net-framework, windows-server-2016

Since yesterday, on one of our Windows Server 2016 machines (hosted on Amazon AWS) we're seeing a spike in CPU utilization. The culprit seems to be ".NET Core Host", in fact if I check the task manager I can see this:

[image]

I cannot find anything online regarding that particular DLL... what is it? What is it doing?

Comment: I’m not finding any good information on it. Find the DLL file and check its properties. It may help confirm if it is a Microsoft file or some other vendor. Looks like this is probably a “t” instance type. Mild CPU usage can cause an over exaggerated impact on system performance when your CPU credits expire and this can be misleading. Check this with cloud watch. It’s possible this service is doing very little but other sustained, mild usage is exhausting all your CPU credits. “t” types don’t guarantee any performance level. Upgrade to a different type to get guaranteed performance.

Comment: That’s a regular application created for the .NET Core Runtime. It just looks like this. The culprit is the “EntitlementProvisioningService” thing. // According to Google, it’s part of this Qlik stuff.

Comment: @DanielB: thanks, that was it, I thought it was part of the runtime, turns out that every NetCore app has a copy of "dotnet.exe" included, which was confusing me. You should reply with a proper answer if you want me to mark it.